# Scope problems with different game levels

Tags: javascript

I have been stuck the whole day with trying to build a level changing mechanism for my game. Basically I have a world map and users load different levels by clicking on the map. But there must be a scope problem since I can't load the levels successfully.

Here is my code:

```
<body onload="start(world001map);"> <!--start the game with the worldmap -->
</body>

function start(whichLevel) {
    whichLevel();
}; 

function world001map(){ //world001map contains everything needed to build the map

    document.getElementById('click_to_start_area')
        .addEventListener("click", //trying start level001
                          function(){
                              start(level001);//white screen
                              //if I do alert(level001) it shows me the content of the level001 function
                          })
}

function level001(){
    //bunch of staff for level001
}
```

Can you spot the weak link? What would be a better way to handle loading different game levels from inside other game levels?

EDIT:

In the risk of sounding stupid (still such a newbie) is there any chance that after all the code for level001 has looped through, we return the "result" of that to the event caller? Instead of staying "in" level001 we just return it's "outcome" which maybe is the problem here? Does that make any sense?

EDIT2:

This might be helpful: If I simply insert the level001 inside onload-statement like  onload="start(level001);"

Then level001 loads properly. So why doesn't it load properly when called from inside the click function?

EDIT3:
After more debugging I have the following thoughts:
The best explanation of why everything works when called directly from body onload might not be the scope of the function call but instead the fact that when I'm loading a level directly from body onload, nothing else has yet been done to the page. I'm now starting to think that the "garbage" from the previous level is somehow stopping the next level from working. My main suspect is the canvas element. And indeed, when I remove everything canvas-related from world001map, the level001 will load (allthough it's running super slowly).

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: No errors, just that nothing happens on start(level001)!
Weirdly alert(level001) does show me the content of level001 function!

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `level001`, does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: "can't load the levels" is a useless description of your issue since you don't show anything of how you try to "load" a level. Where you have the comment `if I do alert(level001) it shows me the content of the level001 function`, that is what should happen.

Comment: I'm not so experienced with the debugger, but it does go to that line and then when I hit "step over" it says "return undefined" under function scope.

Comment: It sounds like everything you've shown in the question is working as intended, and the problem is with the `level001` function itself. If you're uneasy in the debugger, there are tutorials on the web, search for `firebug tutorial` or `chrome developer tools tutorial`.

Comment: But it never goes "inside" the level001 function in the debugger! That's why I thought the content of the level001 function doesn't matter to this problem!

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what you meant by "it does go to that line". If you put the breakpoint at `start(level001)` you need to use "step into" rather than "step over".

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates this?

Comment: @Barmar okay this is new to me and very helpful!! Now I can see that it does indeed go to level001 and thus the problem must indeed lie inside that function!

Comment: @Barmar Ok here's some awfull newbie logic: it almost looks to me like   level001 code runs through properly, but then returns to the eventHandler that called it as "undefined". But I don't want to return to the event handler, I want to start playing the level. Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: This is a web application. Users "play" it by interacting with DOM elements. Your level functions should update the DOM as necessary, and then when the event handler returns the user should be able to play that level.

Comment: First suggestion (not an answer, just a suggestion): use Chrome or Firefox and use their developer tools (Chrome Dev Tools and Firebug respectively). Open up the code and place a breakpoint in the start method. Inspect the value of `whichLevel`. I expect that would be illuminating. Now, I would guess that there is something wrong with your `level001` function.  There may be some error messages in the console.

Comment: The code above looks 100% correct. I suspect the problem you're having is with the level001 function. Show us a minimal implementation of your level function.

Comment: @slebetman It's huge...But here's the weird part: level001 is loaded correctly if I load it directly from the start-function. My problem only occurs when I try to load level001 from inside the click-event..

Comment: Remove as much as possible from the level function while still reproducing the issue of it not doing anything in the onclick handler but does something from onload. Then post THAT function here for us to analyze. BTW, even if you're debugging on your own without the help of Stackoverflow the technique of deleting code until you have the minimum that reproduces the error is a very effective debugging tool.

Comment: @slebetman okay that sounds smart, I will start now. It will probably take an hour or so.

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwjEV/1/) demonstrating that the code you have shown basically works.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be a better way to handle loading different game levels from inside other game levels?

You can use an object with methods that host all the different levels.

```
var levels = {
 'world001map': function () { //world001map contains everything needed to build the map

   document.getElementById('click_to_start_area').addEventListener("click", this.level001)

  },
  'level001': function () {
    //bunch of staff for level001
  }
};

// you may call it using a string
levels['level001']();
```

Put the javascript above the html call

```
 <body onload="levels.world001map();">
```

Comment: Where does it appear that he wants to use strings?

Comment: him passing a undeclared variable into a function call, i assumed he did that because otherwise passing a string will throw `string is not a function` error. so hence given the ability to do it the former way

Comment: Hi! Your solution sounds interesting, but the difficulty is this: because I have so much stuff happening inside each level, I'm defining the levels on separate javascript files for each level. Can I still do that with the technique you have in mind?

Comment: He's not passing any undeclared variables into the function call. `level001` is the name of a defined function.

Comment: do you have access to the file?

Comment: Yes the files are loaded in the head-section

Comment: to add methods: `levels.newLevelMethod = function () {}`, to call new methods stays the same: `levels.newLevelMethod()`. note: levels initiator `var levels = {}` must be load ahead of anything wanting to access it

Comment: The method thing sounds a bit scary to me as such a newbie. Do you think there is any chance that the real problem with my code is that I'm simply returning the outcome of level001 to the event handler instead of actually staying in level001?